# Push Notifications in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, push-notification

How would you implement notifications in flutter in lock screen notifications

I use I custom rest API using asp.net I have I table call notifications,

if any change in this table I went to show I notification to the user

even if the app is closed or the screen Is off

thank you